# Batch moving files from folder to other folder issue

Tags: batch-file

I want to use a batch to move a file (image) from one folder to another. I have made it in the past successfully, but I don't know why it's not working.
I'm not programmer but I had a friend help me with this. Previous time it was working, now not. Am I doing something wrong? Need to change something in the code? The coed I use is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Artwork1
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
move "!file[%rand%]!" C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Artwork2
```

I'll obviously change the path files to the desired ones but is anything off with the code? Some months back it used to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what is not working? How is it not working? Can you elaborate? difficult to guess what is wrong.

Comment: well. I double click it to run it and no image is moved from one folder to the other. The black program screen appears for a split second which means it runs, but no move is done

Comment: On which drive is the script? is the path `C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Artwork` Generic? at the very end of the script add `pause` run it again and tell me what you see.

Comment: C. Like the fodlers. I can paste here the exact code I use with the folder paths. Will check what you edited and let you know

Comment: No, just add `pause` to the bottom of the script, run it again and tell me what it says

Comment: ok, change the 3rd line to exactly this `cd /d "%userprofile%\Dropbox\Artwork1"` then the 7th line to `set "file[!n!]=%%~ff"` and last line to `move "!file[%rand%]!" "%userprofile%\Dropbox\Artwork2"`

Comment: ok. gimme a sec. Ok. It seems to be working. What if I change the paths though?

Can I change it to anything I want after %userprofile%\   ?

Answer (score 0):

To make the script usable on a wider scale, no need to `cd` either:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "in=%userprofile%\Dropbox\Artwork1"
set "out=%userprofile%\Dropbox\Artwork2"
echo Default Input path: %in% Default Output path: %out
set /p "in=Enter Path to copy from (or Press Enter keep Default in path): "
set /p "out=Enter Destination (or Press Enter keep Default out path)
set n=0
for %%f in ("%in%\*.*") do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%~ff"
)
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
move "!file[%rand%]!" "%out%"
```